# log4cxx log without source file path?

Tags: c++, log4cxx

log4cxx pattern `%l` will output the source file name and its path to the log, which makes it uncomfortable to read, if the source file is in in a deep directory, when compiled with a absolute path.

```
2012-11-20 15:59:14,184 0x7f7ae90e27c0 TRACE fogs.common (/home/jw/fogs/d_common/net/inc/amf3conn.hpp:158) - Entering setCallbackObjBuffer
```

is there a way to only output the `amf3conn.hpp:158` in the log, to shorten the log line?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I do not think that this is possible out-of-the-box. According to the [API docs](https://svn.apache.org/repos/asf/logging/site/trunk/docs/log4cxx/apidocs/classlog4cxx_1_1_pattern_layout.html), you can use either `%l` or `%F`, but `%F` only discards the line number and still prints the path.

You have two alternative choices:

- Subclass `PatternLayout` and implement your own handling of location conversion, discarding the path and only using the filename
- Or use the length modifier to set a maximum length for the location, something like `%.20l` which would result in `inc/amf3conn.hpp:158` in your case. If you choose the length of your longest source file name, you get the complete file name in any case (possibly prepended with a part of the path)